# How to round (or perhaps cut) of a float based on some conditions

Tags: python, bots, cryptocurrency, binance

I am trying to make a cryptocurrency bot and I am stuck at a problem. I want to round of the balances based on the data from the exchange because otherwise the exchange doesn’t accept the order request. For example my account contains 0.0044859999999999995 btc and the exchange Stepsize(a fancy name for rounding factor) is 0.00000100, how do I get 0.004485 and not rounded up because then the exchange will give error.
I have tried to do it with the following code.but doesn’t work

```
import sys, signal, json, time
import random
import math
num = 0.0044859999999999995
numCoins = num - math.fmod(num, 0.000001)
print (numCoins) # want to get 0.004485 `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be much better off working with `decimal.Decimal` and not with the language's native `float` type, which is prone to accuracy errors to begin with.

I'd also bet that `0.0044859999999999995 btc` is in fact given to you as a very big integer of smaller units (not sure about btc, but for eth those units are called *wei*).

If that is indeed the case, then you should strive to keep it this way, and do all your math using integers only (i.e., not even `Decimal`, just plain integers and the `//` operation wherever needed).

If you insist on doing it with non-integer values, then you could modify your code to this:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from decimal import getcontext
from decimal import ROUND_DOWN

getcontext().prec = 100
getcontext().rounding = ROUND_DOWN

num = Decimal('0.0044859999999999995')
numCoins = Decimal(int(num*1000000))/1000000
```

Comment: Thanks alot @goodvibration it totally works and wanted these results .thanks alot

Comment: @user11557455: You're welcome, see my recent addition of `ROUND_DOWN` which you might have missed judging by the time of your comment above.

Comment: sure i will check it out ut can you kindly tell me what really decides the round factor i mean like which value this one 1000000 or num*1000000

Comment: In your question, you wrote `0.000001`. To obtain the value used in the answer, do `1 / 0.000001`.

Comment: @NChauhan: Yes, but as I explained in my answer, you should try to avoid using `float` operands in general. So you could write `Decimal(int(num*1000000))/Decimal('0.000001')`, but I don't see any advantage here in terms of generalizing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_DOWN

num = Decimal('0.0044859999999999995')
numCoins = num.quantize(Decimal('0.000001'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
print(numCoins)  # Decimal('0.004485')
```

This Should for you.

Comment: thanks alot I was looking for this kind of thing and if works in every condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_DOWN
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 28
>>> amount = decimal.Decimal('0.0044859999999999995')
>>> step = decimal.Decimal('0.00000100')
>>> rounded_amount=int(amount/step)*step
>>> print(rounded_amount)
0.00448500
>>>
```